# Hardwiring a plugged light

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a light that has a switch on the fixture and then plugs into the wall. I want to wire this directly into a circuit in my camper.

Overall, I'm just looking for a quick explanation of how to do this.

Also, looking at the wiring from the lamp, I only see 2 wire which I assume are the hot and neutral. This leads me to believe it is grounded inside of the fixture. When connecting this light to the circuit, do I also connect the ground wire from my circuit?

Thanks

Comment: The better answer may be to have the switched circuit end in an outlet , and plug the lamp into that. Or to rewire the lamp so it has a proper set of pigtails to wire it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Many cord connected light fixtures do not have a ground. The power going to the light socket is the black or hot wire to the center tab in the fixture, the white or neutral goes to the outer threaded part of the socket. If you want to hard wire this you should use a cord grip where it enters the box to protect the wires from being cut and or being pulled out if someone trips over the cord

Answer (score 0):

National (U.S. ) Electrical Code allows flexible cords for lighting with proper grommets as long as it
Is safe and workmanlike.  However Code does not apply to a vehicle.

Two wires means ungrounded.  Neutral is not ground.

Comment: Actually, Art. 551 *does* apply to his camper/RV

Answer (score 0):

All connections must be made inside of an UL approved enclosure, which means you need to install a box and run some wire, because feeding this directly into a circuit will make it *permanent*.

You'll also need a pendant canopy, the appropriate grommets, and a strain relief.

(sounds like a lot of work to me, just to free up an outlet)